# What's this formula?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

I have to give a formula for $I_\epsilon (\phi)- I_{\epsilon\epsilon_1}(\phi)$ for the case $\epsilon_1^{-1}\in\mathbb{N}$.

I know that $I(\phi)$ is the Integral of the function $\phi$, but what does $\epsilon, \epsilon\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_1^{-1}$ mean in this context?

Comment: In what context? You haven't provided us with any context at all!

Comment: Can you write out the problem you were g8ven wors for word please?

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Unfortunately, the only thing I can tell you is: It has something to do with multidimensional integrals. I don't know additional details myself. At our university, we started with measure and integration theory, but with a somehow weird definition of the multidimensional integral. For reference, see this question [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1486261/281052)

Comment: @SirJective: This is the exact wording of the exercise. The topic is multidimensional integration. I'm sorry that I can't provide any additional information.

Comment: Somewhere in your book, in the section that this exercise is under, it defines this notation. We don't know what book you are using, much less have copies ourselves to go look it up in. You will have to do that.

Comment: @SirJective: It's not from a book. It's an assignment given by our professor, who I am not able to ask right now.

Comment: Then it is a notation he defined in his lecture. Without knowing how the notation is defined, we can't help you. The best I can offer is that I've provided answer to the other question from your link, which attempts to explain the "definition" of integration offered there.